# Read and write requests getting redirected to reader instance in AWS aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We are using aurora mysql with a reader and a writer instance. In spite of using the cluster endpoint, some write requests are being redirected to reader instance and read requests are also getting to reader instance. Is it the expected behaviour in aurora ? If yes, explicitly specifying is the instance is the only solution I believe ?

As per the logs and errors that we are getting, looks like the stale data is being fetched in some reads.

Comment: Reader instances can only serve read requests, so that is definitely not the expected behavior. Are you sure that is what you're observing?

Comment: Yes it is what I am observing. Even we get an error stating “cannot execute with —read only option” and we are using cluster endpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure then. The cluster endpoint is supposed to connect to the primary instance, which by definition is the writer.

Comment: @UjjwalMishra We are going through the same issue. Were you ever able to resolve it? If so, do you mind sharing what you did? It would be really helpful for me. Thanks!

Comment: @jlaverde we are not able to resolve it yet and neither is AWS. Looks like it is the default behaviour to balance the load on primary instance instead of causing requests to fail on primary one. But what we have done is update all major write flows with writer instance endpoint that has significantly reduced the errors on major flows.